# What is the variable and format for fulfillment quantity in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I am using the variable `{{ line_item.fulfillment }}` to show the quantity shipped/fulfilled of any given line item on an order but it shows as "FulfillmentDrop".

What is the real variable for quantity shipped/fulfilled and what is the format?

**Amendment:**

Here is my code block as it appears in Shopify's "Order Printer" app:

`{% for line_item in line_items %}
  <tr>
    <td style="border: none;">{{ line_item.sku }}</td>
    <td style="border: none;">{{ line_item.title }}</td>
    <td style="border: none; text-align: center;">{{ line_item.quantity }}</td>
    <td style="border: none; text-align: center;">{{ line_item.fulfillment.item_count }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on official documentation https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/line_item#line_item-fulfillment

> `line_item.fulfillment` Returns the fulfillment of the line item.

That means, that in your case if you want to receive fulfilled quantity per line item, you should use 
`{{ line_item.fulfillment.item_count }}`

For ***order printer app*** in theory this should work, but it is **not** working for some reason

`{% assign fulfilled_quantity = 0 %}
   {% for f_line_item in fulfilled_line_items %}
      {% if f_line_item.name == line_item.name  %}
            {% assign fulfilled_quantity = f_line_item.quantity %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {{ fulfilled_quantity }}`

`f_line_item.quantity` the variable is always returning full quantity even if you fulfilled partially. I think it is better to ask Shopify support